# Prerequisites for content migration on MOSS 2007 SQL Express to SharePoint Enterprise 2013?

Tags: migration, sql-server

I have MOSS 2007 SP2 on SQL Express.  I'm planning to migrate the content to SharePoint 2013 Enterprise with SQL Server 2014.

I know I need to do a migration to SharePoint 2010 first.

Are there any special steps (other than the regular migration steps) that I need to consider given the difference in SQL versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're aware of the necessity of the SharePoint 2010 intermediary farm, there are no "extra" steps involved specifically related to a migration from an Express edition to a Server edition of SQL.

However, be aware that SharePoint 2010 does not support SQL Server 2014, so you will need to setup a SQL Server version which supports SharePoint 2010 for the intermediary migration farm. This would be one of the following:

SQL Server 2008 SP1 w/ CU2
SQL Server 2008 R2
SQL Server 2012 (with SharePoint 2010 SP1+)

SharePoint 2010 Software Requirements: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(office.14).aspx#section4

SharePoint 2007 SQL Express to SQL Server Migration: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262018(office.12).aspx

Hope this helps!